# How to detect scroll direction on a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a very good solution from stack overflow about how to detect scroll direction and do something but this is working on an another div. I have a div with ID article-container that has scrollbar. I want to detect the scroll direction on this div not on the body or bigger parent div.

There is an onscroll event which has a function and I am trying to do everything inside it but is it causing any problem ...?

HTML

```
<div id="article-container" onscroll="scrollmainup()"> ... text ... </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function scrollmainup(){
var art = document.getElementById("article-container");
document.getElementById("article-container").scrollIntoView({
    block: 'center',
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
this.prev = window.scrollY;
art.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.handleNavigation(e));
handleNavigation = (e) => 
{
const window = e.currentTarget;
if (this.prev > window.scrollY) 
{
    console.log("scrolling up");
} 
else if (this.prev < window.scrollY) 
{
    console.log("scrolling down");
}
this.prev = window.scrollY;
};}
```

I've set art.addEventListener instead of window.addEventListener ... the variable art is not working ... something wrong with const window = e.currentTarget; not sure ... How can I make this code work on the article-container scrollable div ... the code works well on the whole page but not when I scroll the div ... please help me to set the eventlistener correctly ... Thanks in advance ...

Comment: `handleNavigation` just like that leaking into the `window` scope? Why no `const` ? Please create a [mcve]. You're referring to elements in your JS which are not presented in your sample demo.

Comment: I want that scroll direction detection for a specific div. The code works on the whole page scroll up and down. My code is wrong ... that's why asking for help ...